# Mobile Handset List

Tags: mobile, user-agent

I am looking for an open source project where i can get a list of all the mobile phones and detect them via the Browser UserAgent.

I came across one WURFL. But looks like the list hasnt been updated with the latest Android based devices. ( i may be wrong )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WURLF](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) do a good job of keeping the useragent database up to date. And they have a fallback mechanism so that if a specific version you need isn't in the database, it will fall back to a appropriate match so you still get usable data. This works well when a mobile operator may tweak a user agent by modifying say a build number.

However, it was until recently free for use, but (as far as I know) is free for use only on non-commercial projects. You will need to get a license from http://www.scientiamobile.com/ for use on commercial projects.

Comment: looks like i cant use it to get a list of the mobile devices.